# How to link Django and React URLs to perform actions?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

In Django, I have my login URL set to 'api/auth/login'. When given a username and password, it will log that user in. Running 'python manage.py runserver', it will put that URL at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login'

However, my React project, when running 'yarn start' is at 'http://localhost:3000/' and giving it the extension 'api/auth/login', the url it attempts is 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login'.

This does not work, but if I replace the URL extension with 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', the login works as expected.

How can I have the URLs work with my React app? Or is this not something that necessarily needs to be fixed? I do plan to host this project somewhere and am not yet sure how the URLs will work out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hosting react application on another port that's why when you put a request without mentioning host, it gets appended to your current host i.e. 127.0.0.1:3000. I suggest you write "proxy": '127. 0.0.1:8000' in your package.json (refer https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)  and restart your react server or use full url of django server i.e. 127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set `proxy` in the `package.json`.

Second option is to set `axois` `baseURL`:

```
// add in your code before main component definition
// for example in App.js
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
```

I'm preferring the second approach. For doing production build it can be easily overwritten with an environment variable.

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.baseURL = REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
```

Remember to set the CORS headers in the Django server (I'm working on [tutorial](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/) with an example how to do this).